# backspace is not working properly in android phone

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Here is the following code where backspace is not working as it should be. When all digits are filled and we tried to clear the last 6th digit is cleared but keypad hides. On re-tapping on 5th digit keypad appeared but cleared 2 digits (like 5th-4th and 3rd-2nd) on a single backspace tap/click.  I have checked on the Internet as well and tried many solutions but I am not able to solve this issue.

```
class LicenseLoginFragment2 : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel : DataViewModel
    var enteredLicenseCode = ""
    var expDate = ""
    private var oldValues = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

    private var responseSuccess = false

    var myRunnable : Runnable? = null

    var myHandler = Handler()

    var reqBtnClicked = false

    private var licenseVerified = false
    private var invalidLicense = false
    private var expLicense = false
    private var deactivatedLicense = false

    lateinit var mContext : Context

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mContext = requireContext()

        val binding : LicenseLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.license_login, container, false)


        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(DataViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.branchNames.value = mutableListOf()

        licenseBoxListeners(binding)

        /*
        binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
        */

        var netOprtns = NetworkOperations()
        var isNetConnected = false


        return binding.root
    }

    private fun licenseBoxListeners(binding: LicenseLoginBinding) {

        /*
        binding.no1LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        binding.no2LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        binding.no3LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        binding.no4LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        binding.no5LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        binding.no6LicenseLogin.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        */

        licenseBox1(binding)

        licenseBox2(binding)

        licenseBox3(binding)

        licenseBox4(binding)

        licenseBox5(binding)

        licenseBox6(binding)
    }

    private fun licenseBox1(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no1LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no1LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no1LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no1LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no1LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no1LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no1LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace

            }
            false
        }

        binding.no1LicenseLogin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)

                // after click of tick marked (enter) btn on keyboard
                // cursor goes to first box
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();

                var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.mainLicenseLayout.windowToken, 0);

                true
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no1LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no1LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.no2LicenseLogin.setSelection(0)
                    binding.no2LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun licenseBox2(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no2LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no2LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no2LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no2LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no2LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no2LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no2LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.setText("")
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no2LicenseLogin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Done button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)

                // after click of tick marked (enter) btn on keyboard
                // cursor goes to first box
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();

                var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.mainLicenseLayout.windowToken, 0);

                true
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no2LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no2LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.no3LicenseLogin.setSelection(0)
                    binding.no3LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun licenseBox3(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no3LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no3LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no3LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no3LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no3LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no3LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no3LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.setText("")
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no3LicenseLogin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)

                // after click of tick marked (enter) btn on keyboard
                // cursor goes to first box
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();

                var view = requireActivity().currentFocus
                if (view != null) {
                    var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
                }
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no3LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no3LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.no4LicenseLogin.setSelection(0)
                    binding.no4LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun licenseBox4(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no4LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no4LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no4LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no4LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no4LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no4LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no4LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.setText("")
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no4LicenseLogin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)

                // after click of tick marked (enter) btn on keyboard
                // cursor goes to first box
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();

                var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.mainLicenseLayout.windowToken, 0);

                true
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no4LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no4LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.no4LicenseLogin.setSelection(0)
                    binding.no5LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun licenseBox5(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no5LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no5LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no5LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no5LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no5LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no5LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no5LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.setText("")
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no5LicenseLogin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Done button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)

                // after click of tick marked (enter) btn on keyboard
                // cursor goes to first box
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no2LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no4LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();

                var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.mainLicenseLayout.windowToken, 0);

                true
            }
            false
        }

        binding.no5LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no5LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.no6LicenseLogin.setSelection(0)
                    binding.no6LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun licenseBox6(binding : LicenseLoginBinding) {

        binding.no6LicenseLogin.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            //binding.no6LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            if (hasFocus) { //Do your work
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.selectAll()
            }
        }

        binding.no6LicenseLogin.setOnClickListener {
            binding.no6LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = true
            binding.no6LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            binding.no6LicenseLogin.selectAll()
        }

        binding.no6LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) { //this is for backspace
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.requestFocus()
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.setText("")
            }
            false
        }

        /*
        binding.no6LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // User has pressed Back key. So hide the keyboard
                //Log.d("return key pressed  1", "OKKK")
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus();
            }
            false
        }
        */

        binding.no6LicenseLogin.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
            override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                //Log.d("ok", "sir")
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.isCursorVisible = false
                if ((event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    return true
                }
                //Log.d("ok", "sir")
                return false
            }
        })

        binding.no6LicenseLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (binding.no6LicenseLogin.text.isNotEmpty()) {

                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding)
                binding.no6LicenseLogin.clearFocus()
                binding.no1LicenseLogin.setSelectAllOnFocus(false)
                var imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.mainLicenseLayout.windowToken, 0);
            }
        })
    }

    private fun checkLicenseBoxesFilled(binding: LicenseLoginBinding) {

        enteredLicenseCode = binding.no1LicenseLogin.text.toString() + binding.no2LicenseLogin.text.toString() +
                binding.no3LicenseLogin.text.toString() + binding.no4LicenseLogin.text.toString() +
                binding.no5LicenseLogin.text.toString() + binding.no6LicenseLogin.text.toString()
        if (enteredLicenseCode.length == 6) {
            binding.next.isEnabled = true
            binding.next.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.button_rounded_corners)
        } else {
            binding.next.isEnabled = false
            binding.next.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.button_disabled_rounded_corners)
        }
    }
}
```

The screen recording is as follows:
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of your problem is that a KeyEventListener would fire twice-  once for down and once for up.  You need to only delete data on a down, not an up.  Basically ignore all ups.

Your next big problem is that most keyboards don't send key events at all, they send commit text events and deletion events.  So the chance is it won't fire at all.  Key events are generally for physical keys-  bluetooth keyboards, the rare phone with a slide out keyboard, and buttons like volume.  Softkeyboards have a better interface that avoids key events.